# Why does my bevel crease disappear when I add a Subdivision Modifier?

Tags: edit-mode

I created a custom crease in the bevel modifier in the upper section. I want to smooth it out a bit. However, it disappears as soon as I add a Subdivision Modifier, see 2nd picture.

I want to keep the crease in the shape as visible in the first picture.

Here is the file: [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The Subdivision Surface will tend to round the shapse and make the concave bevel disappear, if you want to avoid that for some edges, bevel them themselves or use Ctrl E > Edge Crease. What shape would you like exactly?

Comment: I want to keep the shape as it is in the first picture, but I just want to smooth it out a bit.

Comment: why dont you just increase the bevel resolution?

Answer (score 0):

The *Subdivision Surface* will tend to round the shape and make the concave bevel disappear, if you want to avoid that for some edges, put a second *Bevel* modifier in order to sharp the edges created by the first *Bevel* modifier, or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Edge Crease* on the edge that you want to keep sharp:

[image]